# Result type for groupby.apply() method depends on explicitly used index when dataframe-to-series function is used?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, apply

The groupby.apply() method has strange behavior when applied on dataframe-to-series function.

Having these test data

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame([['A', 2], 
                     ['B', 3], 
                     ['A', 4], 
                     ['B', 5]], 
                    columns=['mygroups', 'value'])
```

when I use function returning a Series with input data index it produces a Series

```
def func1(df):
    return pd.Series([5, 6], index=df.index)

print(data.groupby(['mygroups']).apply(func1))
```

```
mygroups   
A         0    5
          2    6
B         1    5
          3    6
dtype: int64
```

but it produces DataFrame when in the return function there is just Series with automatic index

```
def func2(data):
    return pd.Series([5, 6])

print(data.groupby(['mygroups']).apply(func2))
```

```
          0  1
mygroups      
A         5  6
B         5  6
```

Apparently in one case the returning Series is put in rows while in the other it is put in columns. Why?

Comment: Yes, so basically when the index in function return is constant then apply() produces a DataFrame. When it changes a Series with multi index is produced. Thanks!